# Visualize Nginx logs in grafana with ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, grafana

I've an Elasticsearch installation which collects nginx's logs which I need to visualize in Grafana in the following way:

- top browsers which access certain url. let's suppose index.html
- count opens of certain web page supposing same ip and user agent as one

Data Structure stored in elasticsearch is same to

```
"_index" : "redacted",
   "_type" : "_doc",
   "_id" : "redacted",
   "_score" : 0.9736392,
   "_source" : {
     "upstream_status" : "302",
     "@timestamp" : "2019-11-26T03:02:08.754Z",
     "http_referer" : "-",
     "ecs" : { },
     "body_bytes_sent" : "0",
     "host" : { },
     "time_local" : "26/Nov/2019:03:02:08 +0000",
     "the_real_ip" : "redacted",
     "message" : "redacted - [redacted] - - [26/Nov/2019:03:02:08 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/2.0\" 302 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36\" 220 0.005 [production-webadmin-80] redacted:8080 0 0.004 302 979897183c421507eaea8346eeb5904c",
     "proxy_upstream_name" : "production-webadmin-80",
     "remote_user" : "-",
     "service" : "ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx-internal",
     "request_time" : "0.005",
     "upstream_response_time" : "0.004",
     "tags" : [
       "_geoip_lookup_failure"
     ],
     "upstream_addr" : "redacted:8080",
     "user_agent" : {
       "device" : "Other",
       "patch" : "3865",
       "os_major" : "10",
       "build" : "",
       "minor" : "0",
       "name" : "Chrome",
       "major" : "77",
       "os" : "Mac OS X",
       "os_name" : "Mac OS X",
       "os_minor" : "14"
     },
     "geoip" : { },
     "kubernetes" : {
       "pod" : {
         "name" : "redacted-internal-76dd64fb5f-stj99"
       },
       "container" : {
         "name" : "redacted"
       },
       "labels" : {
         "app" : "ingress-nginx-internal",
         "appId" : "ingress-nginx"
       },
       "namespace" : "ingress-nginx",
       "replicaset" : {
         "name" : "redacted-internal-76dd64fb5f"
       },
       "node" : {
         "name" : "redacted-20190904071-128f9703-gnvr"
       }
     },
     "request" : "GET / HTTP/2.0",
     "http_user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
     "stream" : "stdout",
     "request_length" : "220",
     "upstream_response_length" : "0",
     "status" : "302",
     "input" : { }
```

Now I've no idea how to do this using grafana. one thing I was able to get working was a query like

```
request : index.html AND status : 200
```

Could anubody help?